# When trying to use GL3W.h: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wBindTexture'

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use GL3W to get the function pointers for an OpeGL framework that I am making. Anytime that I include gl3w.h in the project, I get 28 errors. Here they are:

> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(74): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wBindTexture'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(74): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(140): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wCopyTexImage1D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(140): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(141): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wCopyTexImage2D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(141): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(142): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wCopyTexSubImage1D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(142): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(143): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wCopyTexSubImage2D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(143): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(178): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wDeleteTextures'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(178): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(195): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wDrawArrays'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(195): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(201): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wDrawElements'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(201): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(241): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wGenTextures'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(241): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(299): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wGetPointerv'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(299): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(410): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'gl3wIsTexture'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(410): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(464): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wPolygonOffset'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(464): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(572): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wTexSubImage1D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(572): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(573): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'gl3wTexSubImage2D'
>
> 1>c:\projects\project_boxes\exlib\ogl_headers\gl\gl3w.h(573): error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int 2>  Killer1_Engine.vcxproj ->
>   C:\Projects\Killer1_Engine\Build\Killer1_Engine....\Bin\Win32Debug\Killer1_Engine_Win32_Debug.lib
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I downloaded the source code from the GL3W site, and have tried it both after compiling the code into a static library (.lib) and with just including the .c file, and the headers. When I compile the library, it works without issues, but its whenever I link to it that I have issues. I would really like to use this library, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you including the header file **before** any other OpenGL files?

Comment: You, good sir, are a genius. I thought I had, because I had seen that before, but then I thought myself, "What about before the windows.h, because can't that have OGL stuff in it".

I move the gl3w.h into my standard header (I call it Atom.h) above the windows.h, and boom, no more error. Thank you so much. I lost sleep over this one.